# Login users at the same time problems in signalr

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm working on a social network with ASP.NET and signalr. I have a simple login page, if it finds the user in the database it creates an Application variable and redirect the user to the profile page and in this page i invoke my Connect method declared in my hub class, this method takes the userid in the session and it give the friend list of this user. That works great when two or many users logged in at different time. The thing is, when two or several users logged in at the same time, the connect method declared in my hub takes the last user id stored in the Application variable and it give the friend list of this last user id and it send it to all user connected.

I can't find the correct approach.

Loggin Page code:

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tbl_User user = new Tbl_User();
    user = FonctionCommun.Login(txt_UserName.Text , txt_PassWord.Text);
    if (user != null)
    {
        Application["UserID"] = user.UserID.ToString();    
        Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");
    }
    else {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

My connect method code:

```
public void connect()
{           
 UserID = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Application["UserID"].ToString());

 string OutPut = "";

 if (ListOnlineUser.Count(x => x.UserID == UserID) == 0)
 {
 ListOnlineUser.Add(new OnlineUsers { UserID = UserID, ConnetionID = Guid.Parse(Context.ConnectionId) });
                objchat.SetOnline(UserID);     
                ListFriends = objchat.GetFriendLoginStatus(UserID);
            }
            foreach (Tbl_User item in ListFriends)
            {
                if (item.Status == "1")
                {
                    OnlineUsers onlineFriend = ListOnlineUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == Guid.Parse(item.UserID.ToString()));
                    if (onlineFriend != null)
                    {
                        using (FIESTA_ADVISOREntities BD = new FIESTA_ADVISOREntities())
                        {
                            Tbl_User Obj_User = BD.Tbl_User.Where(o => o.UserID == UserID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (Obj_User.ProfileImage != null)
                            {
                                string ext = BD.Assets.Where(o => o.url == Obj_User.ProfileImage).Select(o => o.MimeType).FirstOrDefault();
                                UserDetaille res = new UserDetaille() { UserID = Guid.Parse(Obj_User.UserID.ToString()), Username = Obj_User.UserName, ProfileImage = Obj_User.ProfileImage.ToString(), Ext = ext };
                                 OutPut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
                            }
                            else { 
                                UserDetaille res = new UserDetaille() { UserID = Guid.Parse(Obj_User.UserID.ToString()), Username = Obj_User.UserName, ProfileImage = "111", Ext = "png" }; 
                                OutPut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res); }

                            Clients.Client(onlineFriend.ConnetionID.ToString()).OnNewUserConnect(OutPut);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Clients.Caller.ShowFriends(ListFriends);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try session variable instead of application variable. Application variable shared through out application working. So Whenever new user  this is override. But if you use session variable that will never override by any other user

Comment: when I use the variable session I get an error message in the metohde connect "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."                  in this line                                                                                            UserID =Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString());

Comment: opps this Connect method in chatHub class so you will have to use cookies :)

Just after login the create a cookie and access that cookie in chathub connect method

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use query string in signalr in which you can pass userid as query string so in each request userid will be in query string

```
 $.connection.hub.qs = 'userid=' + "UserId";
```

Comment: No need to use hidden field. as user id is sensitive info. So better is encrypt the user id and set query string of signalR  $.connection.hub.qs = 'userid=' + "UserId"; and then you can get this value in each request send by signalr to server